# how to find p-value of proportion values on R

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, p-value, ggpubr

| age categories | false positive count | total count | proportion (FP/Total) % |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 40 - 45 | 25 | 100 | 25.0 |
| 45 - 50 | 25 | 68 | 36.8 |
| 50 - 55 | 50 | 250 | 20.0 |
| 55 - 60 | 82 | 317 | 25.9 |

I have this data frame on R.
it shows the false positive counts and the total count within each respective age categories.
I have also added a column with the calculated % of False positives / total count.

Essentially, I want to be able to plot this as a graph - which I can do.

```
graph <- ggplot(data = hi, aes(x = age_categories, y = prop)) +   geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "light blue") + labs(x = "percentage", y = "Percentage of False Positives", 
fill = NULL ,title = " False Positives by age categories")
```

But I am struggling to find the P values to show if there is any significant different in the false positive counts between each of the age categories.

So for e.g I want to see if there is a significant difference (P-value) between those between '40-45' and the other age categories.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: There are many different ways of conducting inference on a proportion. A typical approach would be an ANOVA to get a chi-square test statistics. You would usually want to use the raw data instead of the aggregates you calculated. You also could bootstrap it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to perform single factor ANOVA in R with samples organized by column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14206154/how-to-perform-single-factor-anova-in-r-with-samples-organized-by-column)

Answer (score 0):

So basically you want the chi-square for this table, if I understand correctly your question:

| Age group | FP | TP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 40-45 | 25 | 75 |
| 45 - 50 | 25 | 43 |
| 50 - 55 | 50 | 200 |
| 55 - 60 | 82 | 235 |

You can get an overall P-value by calculating a chi-square statistic for that table:

```
cbind(c(25,25,50,82), c(75,43,200,235)) |> chisq.test()
```

If you want to specifically contrast the first level with the others, you can use a logistic regression:

```r
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
df <- tribble(
  ~ age_group, ~FP, ~TP, ~weight,
  1, 1, 0, 25,
  1, 0, 1, 75,
  2, 1, 0, 25,
  2, 0, 1, 43,
  3, 1, 0, 50,
  3, 0, 1, 200,
  4, 1, 0, 82,
  4, 0, 1, 235
) |> 
  mutate(age_group = factor(age_group))

glm(FP ~ age_group, family=binomial, weight=weight, data=df) |> summary()
#> 
#> Call:
#> glm(formula = FP ~ age_group, family = binomial, data = df, weights = weight)
#> 
#> Deviance Residuals: 
#>       1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8  
#>   8.325   -6.569    7.073   -6.278   12.686   -9.448   14.892  -11.861  
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
#> (Intercept) -1.09861    0.23094  -4.757 1.96e-06 ***
#> age_group2   0.55629    0.34145   1.629    0.103    
#> age_group3  -0.28768    0.27988  -1.028    0.304    
#> age_group4   0.04575    0.26417   0.173    0.863    
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)
#> 
#>     Null deviance: 822.77  on 7  degrees of freedom
#> Residual deviance: 814.55  on 4  degrees of freedom
#> AIC: 822.55
#> 
#> Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Changing the factor levels or the contrast matrix you can also get P-values for any of the levels compared to the others.